# Providing google maps from a local server behind a firewall or a proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, nginx

I am using Google Maps in my web application, The web server have access to internet but the users cannot access the web, only my server. How can I make Google Maps work in such case?

Is there a way to proxy the maps from Google to users?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do something like this with google maps. (Of course you could emulate a browser and "screenshot" that page).

But Open Street Map offers you a great API with to possibility to download a part of the map and everything for free.

Great wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API